# How to delete first text? (c#)

Tags: c#, regex, replace, split

I want to code

```
var text = "14. hello my friends we meet 1 test, 2 baby 3 wiki 4 marvel";
string[] split = text.Split('14.', 1, 2, 3, 4);
var needText = split[0].Replace('14.', '');
```

"1" "2" "3" "4" is static text.

but, "14." is dynamic text.

ex)

```
var text2 = "1972. google youtube. 1 phone, 2 star 3 tv 4 mouse";
string[] split = text.Split('1972.', 1, 2, 3, 4);
var needText = split[0].Replace('1972.', '');
```

Comment: Is the '.' always after the first number?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have dynamic separators like this, `String.Split` is not suitable. Use `Regex.Split` instead.

You can give a *pattern* to `Regex.Split` and it will treat every substring that matches the pattern as a separator.

In this case, you need a pattern like this:

```
\d+\. |1|2|3|4
```

`|` are `or` operators. `\d` matches any digit character. `+` means match between 1 to unlimited times. `\.` matches the dot literally because `.` has special meaning in regex.

Usage:

```
var split = Regex.Split(text, "\\d+\\. |1|2|3|4");
```

And I think the text you need is at index 1 of `split`.

Remember to add a using directive to `System.Text.RegularExpressions`!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `IndexOf()` with `Substring()`, you can very easily grab the information you need. If it's any more complex than your examples then use Regex.

```
var text = "14. hello my friends we meet 1 test, 2 baby 3 wiki 4 marvel";
var strArr = text.Substring(text.IndexOf(' ')).Split('1', '2', '3', '4');
```